# Update Oxyplot C# WPF on demand

Tags: c#, wpf, robotics, fuzzy-logic, oxyplot

I am experimenting with a robotic arm and fuzzy logic. My goal is to plot the membership function *(simple triangle and trapezoid functions)* created by the user. The oxy Plot 'object' is located on an expander, which is located on MainWindow. Plot selection will most likely be from a drop-down or text-box.

**Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to update a plot with new information. All of the examples appear to be dynamic, based on time. But I need it to be based on user demand!** The closest examples I can find are the [Refresh](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Examples/WPF/WpfExamples/Examples/RefreshDemo/Window1.xaml.cs) and [Task](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Examples/WPF/WpfExamples/Examples/TaskDemo/MainWindow.xaml.cs) demo files, *I think*.

Up to now I have been able to produce an original, blank plot with a title and axes using the following syntax:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    private PlotModel plotModel;

    public PlotModel PlotModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.plotModel;
        }
        set
        {
            this.plotModel = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.PlotModel = CreatePlot("mag1");
    }


    private PlotModel CreatePlot(string title)
    {
        var pm = new PlotModel(title);

        return pm;
    }
```

And the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="FuzzyGripper.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000" Closing="Window_Closing" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

...... A ton of stuff ...... then......

<oxy:Plot x:Name="plot1" Model="{Binding PlotModel}"/>
```

The problem comes when I want to update the plot with something as simple as a new title. From what I can tell the OxyPlot can only be updated when the object is located in the MainWindow constructor. For example the following snippet is called after the original plot is created (*outside of MainWindow(){}*):

```
this.plotModel = CreatePlot("Mag2");
plot1.RefreshPlot(true);
```

It doesn't work. The original plot remains, with title "Mag1". I have a feeling I missing something related to context, specifically -- DataContext -- but I am not extremely comfortable with the language, so I am stuck! With that being said, I am not completely sold on Oxyplot. If there is a better approach I am willing to give it a try. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind using the `PlotModel` in OxyPlot is to use MVVM, so you shouldn't really use the Codebehind to do what you're trying to do. You should check first the [concept of MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) which is quite important for WPF and then look at different MVVM Frameworks to help you with it, like [Caliburn Micro](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) or [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)

The issue with your code is that when you're doing `this.plotModel = CreatePlot("Mag2")`, you're creating a new PlotModel object, WPF then loses the binding that he had with the old objects. You should notify him (implementing `INotifyPropertyChange`) that the PlotModel property has changed.

But anyway, to change the title you shouldn't re-create a whole PlotModel, you should simply do something like `this.PlotModel.Title = "Mag2"`.

Also, the PlotModel itself has a refresh method, it's better to call this one instead of calling the Plot's refresh.

Good luck.